# Python: Tkinter stopping due to while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, tkinter

I am trying to run a while loop inside my program, but when the while loop is in place, the code stops, and the tkinter window does not open. How do I solve this? It should be so that the code writes out two random numbers, and then when the correct answer is input, it should re-loop.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk() 

#Frames
topFrame = Frame(root) # I want an invisible container in root
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root) # I want an invisible container in root
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
#End Of Frames

#Addition Question Maker



AnswerBox = Entry(topFrame)
AnswerBox.grid(row=0,column=4)
EqualsSign = Label(topFrame, text="=").grid(row=0,column=3)
AdditionSign = Label(topFrame, text="+").grid(row=0,column=1)

NewQuestion = True

while NewQuestion == True:
    AdditionQuestionLeftSide = random.randint(0, 10)
    AdditionQuestionRightSide = random.randint(0, 10)
    global Total
    Total = AdditionQuestionLeftSide + AdditionQuestionRightSide
    AdditionQuestionRightSide = Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionRightSide).grid(row=0,column=0)
    AdditionQuestionLeftSide= Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionLeftSide).grid(row=0,column=2)
    answer = None


def OutputAnswerText(event):
    global answer
    answer = AnswerBox.get()
    if Total == int(answer):
      Correct = Label(topFrame, text="Correct").grid(row=2,column=3)
      NewQuestion = True
    else:
       Correct = Label(topFrame, text="Wrong").grid(row=2,column=3)

AnswerBox.bind('<Return>', OutputAnswerText)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a while loop, I suggest making NewQuestion a function. The function gets called initially, then if the answer is correct the function gets called again. Here is my code for the function, along with an automatic entry delete option to remove the need to backspace your answer after inputting a correct answer.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk() 

#Frames
topFrame = Frame(root) # I want an invisible container in root
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root) # I want an invisible container in root
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
#End Of Frames

#Addition Question Maker



AnswerBox = Entry(topFrame)
AnswerBox.grid(row=0,column=4)
EqualsSign = Label(topFrame, text="=").grid(row=0,column=3)
AdditionSign = Label(topFrame, text="+").grid(row=0,column=1)


def NewQuestion():
    AdditionQuestionLeftSide = random.randint(0, 10)
    AdditionQuestionRightSide = random.randint(0, 10)
    global Total
    Total = AdditionQuestionLeftSide + AdditionQuestionRightSide
    AdditionQuestionRightSide = Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionRightSide).grid(row=0,column=0)
    AdditionQuestionLeftSide= Label(topFrame, text= AdditionQuestionLeftSide).grid(row=0,column=2)
    answer = None
    return

NewQuestion()

def OutputAnswerText(event):
    global answer
    global AnswerBox
    answer = AnswerBox.get()
    if Total == int(answer):
      Correct = Label(topFrame, text="Correct").grid(row=2,column=3)
      AnswerBox.delete(0, END)
      NewQuestion()
    else:
       Correct = Label(topFrame, text="Wrong").grid(row=2,column=3)

AnswerBox.bind('<Return>', OutputAnswerText)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an infinite loop:

```
while NewQuestion == True:
```

There is no place where NewQuestion can become false (and no break in the loop). So the loop is infinite.

Also:

```
EqualsSign = Label(topFrame, text="=").grid(row=0,column=3)
```

doesn't work because `grid` returns `None`. If you want to keep a reference to the widget, you have to use the two-lines version like in:

```
AnswerBox = Entry(topFrame)
AnswerBox.grid(row=0,column=4)
```